# Giving S_IWUGO permission to module parameter results in compilation error (while S_IRUGO or S_IXUGO doesn't) - why?

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-kernel, compilation

I wrote a simple kernel module to learn module_param feature of the kernel module. However, if I give the  `S_IWUGO, S_IRWXUGO` or `S_IALLUGO` permissions for the `perm` field, I get the follwing compilation error:

```
[root@localhost param]# make -C $KDIR M=$PWD modules 
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.11.10-301.fc20.i686+PAE'
  CC [M]  /root/ldd/misc/param/param/hello.o
/root/ldd/misc/param/param/hello.c:6:168: error: negative width in bit-field ‘<anonymous>’
 module_param(a, int, S_IWUGO);
                                                                                                                                                                        ^
make[1]: *** [/root/ldd/misc/param/param/hello.o] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/root/ldd/misc/param/param] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.11.10-301.fc20.i686+PAE'
```

Compilation is successful for `S_IRUGO or S_IXUGO` (permission not containing Write permssion). I suppose I must be doing something wrong because from what I know, wrtie permission is legal. What am I doing wrong here?

The program:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/stat.h>

int a = 2;

module_param(a, int, S_IXUGO);

int f1(void){

        return 0;
}

void f2(void){

}

module_init(f1);
module_exit(f2);

MODULE_AUTHOR("lavya");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("experiment with parameters");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux does not accept the [S_IWOTH](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/stat.h?v=3.11) permission.
If you follow the macro chain behind module_param, you arrive to  [__module_param_call](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h?v=3.11#L176) which includes:

```
BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perm) < 0 || (perm) > 0777 || ((perm) & 2))
```

`S_IWOTH == 2` so the test fails.

The `negative width in bit-field` error is merely is an artefact of the [implementation of BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/bug.h?v=3.11#L33)

Linux probably refuses to make module parameters world-writable for security reasons. You should be able to use narrower permissions such as `S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP`.